# Sending default value by POST request <form></form>.Django, HTML

Tags: html, django, post, request

i want to send on post request default value

index.html

```
          <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Имя" name="first_name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Фамилия" name="last_name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="phone_number">
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-1">
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Электронная почта" name="email">
                <input name="P">
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Зарегистрироваться!</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

this is my Views.py

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
    last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
    phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    status = request.POST.get('P')
    print(first_name,last_name,phone_number,email,status)

    s=UserReg(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,phone_number=phone_number,email=email)
    s.save()
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

This is what command print(request) shows:

```
[24/Jul/2020 16:01:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8089
sasha weltay +1111111 azw@ksdpi.ru None
```

I just wanna send value"P" by the to my views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hidden input element: `<input type="hidden" name="P" value="{DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND}">`

Answer (score -1):

index.html

```
<input type="hidden" name="P" value="your data">
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    status = request.POST.get('P')
    print(status)
```

result ==> "your data"